# Algebraic K theory, Karoubi completion and splitting

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{C}\subset \mathcal{C}'$ is a pair of pre-triangulated smooth DG categories over a characteristic-zero basefield (say, $\mathbb{C}$), such that $\mathcal{C}$ is faithfully embedded in $\mathcal{C}'$ and $\mathcal{C}'$ is the Karoubi completion of $\mathcal{C}.$ Then it is classically known that the map on Grothendieck groups $K^0(\mathcal{C})\to K^0(\mathcal{C}')$ is an embedding, and a rational equivalence: in particular, if $K^0(\mathcal{C}')$ is torsion-free, then there is no splitting of the map, $K^0(\mathcal{C})\leftarrow K^0(\mathcal{C}').$

My question is whether it is possible for there to be a non-trivial splitting over the Quillen K-theory coefficient ring spectrum $K^*(\mathbb{C})$ of the map of module spectra $K^*(\mathcal{C})\to K^*(\mathcal{C}').$ This question came up in studying the algebraic K theory of a p-adic group.

Comment: Could you give an example when the map on $K^0$ is not an isomorphism?

Comment: Sure. Take complexes of vector spaces of even total dimension.

Comment: I doubt that any property of pre-triangulated smooth DG categories (that is not valid in some more general context) may be classically known.:) So, could you give a reference?

Comment: Your premise is false: the map on $K^0$ is not a rational isomorphism. Just take the subcategory of objects with trivial class in $K^0$. See [Thomason's Classification of triangulated subcategories](https://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1017932514274).